# Getting Non-Zero Indices of a tensor in Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get non-zero indices from a tfjs tensor in javascript. I've tried using whereAsync but this returns a promise which is a hassle to solve or do anything with. Is there an easier way to get the non-zero indices?